# How to get multiple rows if where clause has repeated condition values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch all the rows using `WHERE IN (...ids)` format.This is working fine. But if ids inside `IN` are repeated only one row for that ID is returned by default by SQL.

Is there a way i can get same row `N` times if the `ID` is present `N` times in`WHERE IN (...ids)`?

Ex:
**Data in Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

**Query**
`SELECT * FROM people WHERE id IN (1, 2, 2, 3);`

**Result**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

**Expected Result**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

Is there a way to get this result in SQL?

I am using Postgres.

Thank you

| 3   | CCC            |

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clauses do not -- as a general rule -- change the number of rows.  Instead, use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (2), (3)) v(id) JOIN
     people p
     USING (id);
```

Note:  If you want all ids in the list, even those not in `people` use `LEFT JOIN`.

If you want to pass in the values as a parameter, then arrays are more convenient than `VALUES()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 2, 3]) v(id) JOIN
     people p
     USING (id);
```